# Improper Integrals Type

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> State whether the following integral is of Type I or Type II and whether it is convergent or divergent:
>
> $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \exp\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-x\right) \ dx $$

I thought it would be both Type I and Type II because of the infinite domain and the discontinuity at x = 1, but the answers claim that it is just a Type I improper integral.

Also, how could I determine the convergence / divergence of this?

Comment: Type 1 and Type 2 being what?

Comment: $\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-x\right)$ decays extremely rapidly for $x \ge 1$, so convergence is definitely guaranteed. Note that for $x \ge 1, \exp\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-x\right) \le e^{-x}$

Comment: Note the singularity at $x=1$ is removable, so we can choose to define the  value of the function at the point to be $0$. Nevertheless, the integral is unaffected by this. We still have an improper (Riemann) integral though because the upper limit is infinity

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Why is the singularity at x = 1 removable?

Comment: the limit exists at the point.

Comment: The improper Riemann integrability has little to do with the continuity at a point. $\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-x\right)$ is positive and bounded by $e^{-x}$ (which is an integrable function) on $(1,+\infty)$, hence your integral is convergent.